# Is only using references the most idiomatic/efficient for "big" structures?

Tags: rust

Consider the case of a "big" structure such as one containing several `BigInt` variables. For example:

```
struct BigStruct {
    x: BigInt,
    y: BigInt,
    z: BigInt,
}
```

My current understanding of Rust is the following:

1. I should not implement Copy on such a structure.
2. I should manipulate it through references.

Both of these are for performance reasons.

This structure is mainly read-only as its parameters generally don't change once they have been set. Nevertheless, elements of that structure are often used to generate new ones (through operator overriding) as in the following example:

```
let b1: BigStruct = BigStruct { ... } // Rarely change
let b2: BigStruct = BigStruct { ... } // Rarely change
let b3: BigStruct = &b1 + &b2 // Often combined by operations
```

Can you confirm that my approach (no `Copy`, all references) is the most idiomatic/efficient for this use case? It seems to have at least two drawbacks:

- If someone want to use my code, they will need to think whether they should use a reference or not from context. I would like to hide this complexity to have the simplest API possible.
- I must override each operator twice. For instance, I must provide `Add<Self>` and `Add<&Self>` to override addition.

Comment: Better post this question to [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: hypothetical code is off topic at Code Review, so don't post this question there

Comment: Does `BigInt` implement `Copy`?  If not then you probably derive `Copy` anyway.

Comment: BigInt does not implement Copy. I am not sure to understand what do you mean by "probably derive it anyway", can you elaborate ?

Comment: @comrade you should probably read [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/5777/32521) before suggesting that something applies there ;-)

Comment: @Shepmaster sure, thanks :)

Comment: @frlk: Chris meant that even if you try to `#[derive(Copy)]` on `BigStruct`, rustc will not because this is only possible if all data members are `Copy` already.

Answer (score 0):

Two (partial) solutions that may solve the initial problem :

**Go full references but not as described in the question**

- Manipulate only `&BigStruct` ;
- Pass `&BigStruct` as function parameters ;
- Override operators only for `&BigStruct`.

The previous example would be :

```
let b1: &BigStruct = &BigStruct { ... } 
let b2: &BigStruct = &BigStruct { ... } 
let b3: &BigStruct = &(b1 + b2)
```

The main problem of this approach is that functions and operators will return `BigStruct` rather than `&BigStruct` which is not convenient for users especially when doing arithmetic (it forces to add a `&` every time an operation is performed).

**Use owned pointers**

This use-case may be a legitimate exception for using pointers for efficiency as mentionned in [Pointers in Rust : a guide](http://words.steveklabnik.com/pointers-in-rust-a-guide). Concretely, we can :

- Manipulate only `Box<BigStruct>` ;
- Pass and return `Box<BigStruct>` in function ;
- Override operators only for `Box<BigStruct>`.

The previous example would be :

```
let b1: Box<BigStruct> = Box::new(BigStruct { ... }) 
let b2: Box<BigStruct> = Box::new(BigStruct { ... }) 
let b3: Box<BigStruct> = b1 + b2
```

In this case, arithmetic is very straighforward. This approach has nevertheless some drawbacks :

- Working explicitely with pointers is not idiomatic Rust ;
- Returning pointers from functions is considered a poor Rust practice.